# Does PHP's fread() always read at least 4096 bytes?

Tags: php, file

According to Drupal 7's bootstrap file:

```
// PHP only performs buffered reads, so in reality it will always read
// at least 4096 bytes. Thus, it costs nothing extra to read and store
// much so as to speed any additional invocations.
```

PHP will always read 4096 no matter if you specified a lower value for the `length` parameter. Is this true? If so, is there really no way to do unbuffered reads?

Edit: I'd like to read `/dev/urandom` without consuming entropy unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I got a function for you in PHP - stream_set_read_buffer():

```
int stream_set_read_buffer ( resource $stream , int $buffer )
```

buffer : The number of bytes to buffer. If buffer is 0 then read operations are unbuffered. This ensures that all reads with fread() are completed before other processes are allowed to write to that output stream.

So, if you want to change the default behavior then this function should be useful to experiment.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a file of less than 4096 bytes then it would be less, or padded with null values I'd imagine.

What's wrong with a 4096 byte long buffer anyway - it's too small to affect memory consumption in any major way, unless there's something I'm missing here.

Comment: For your purposes, I think 4096 bytes is fine - `/dev/urandom` will keep generating entropy forever. If your program takes 4096 bytes (4KB) of that, it will take microseconds to read, maybe even less, which means more entropy can take it's place and be used by other processes almost instantly.

Comment: I don't think it's fine. If I need, say, 16 bytes of pseudo random data, it makes no sense to bring the entropy source 4096 bytes closer to exhaustion. Do you have any proof or experiments on yours thoughts?

Comment: No, I don't - sorry. You do make a very good point, however. I was thinking you wanted quite a bit of entropy (e.g. 2048 bytes), which is OK due to it being a much larger amount of the full 4096 bytes. You are very correct in saying 4096 bytes is overkill for 16 bytes of wanted data.

Comment: Satya Prakash's post below describes a way of playing around with things.

Answer (score 0):

A possible work-around for PHP < 5.3 would seem to be to use file_get_contents():

```
$output = file_get_contents('/dev/urandom', FALSE, NULL, -1, $bytes);
```

The invocation is a little ugly.  Not sure how to confirm it's unbuffered, however, other than reading the C source.

http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/branches/PHP_5_2/ext/standard/file.c?revision=298881&view=markup

http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/branches/PHP_5_2/main/streams/streams.c?revision=293175&view=markup

It doesn't look like the input stream is flagged to be unbuffered, so it seems this also reads at least the minimum buffer size out of it on PHP 5.2.

Comment: It is buffered, unfortunately. I've just tested it with with a user-space stream.